# kdb q How to recognize and connect rows of data where there are same IDs

Tags: kdb

I need to find a way to match and combine similar rows where IDs from different columns match.

This is what my table looks like:

| FirstID | SecondID | SomeMoreData |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123ABC | 456DEF | ... |
| 456DEF | 789GHI | ... |
| 349UYH | 286IWD | ... |

I am trying to find the rows where the FirstID and SecondID are matched.

For example, the SecondID of row 1 (456DEF) and the FirstID of row 2 are the same, so those are connected.

My plan is to make a third column to connect these two rows, with the final output being the following:

| Source ID | FirstID | SecondID | SomeMoreData |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123ABC | 123ABC | 456DEF | ... |
| 123ABC | 456DEF | 789GHI | ... |
| 349UYH | 349UYH | 286IWD | ... |

In the table above, the first two rows' values in the Source ID column are 123ABC, because the first row's FirstID is not connected to another row's SecondID, whereas the 2nd row does. For this second row, we find the original FirstID that isn't connected, and use that value as the Source ID.

Let me know if this makes sense!

My pseudocode is below:

`if (SecondID is found in FirstID):`

`x: FirstID where SecondID = this row's FirstID`

`update SourceID: x`

`else: SourceID: this row's FirstID`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be helpful if you provide the input in the future.
You can do something like this:

```
q)input:([] FirstID:`123ABC`456DEF`349UYH; SecondID:`456DEF`789GHI`286IWD)
q)dictMap:(!).(select distinct SecondID,FirstID from input)`SecondID`FirstID
q)dictMap / Dict mapping if it finds the FirstID
456DEF| 123ABC
789GHI| 456DEF
286IWD| 349UYH
q)update SourceId:dictMap FirstID from input / If SourceId is empty we want to fill it using FirstID^
FirstID SecondID SourceId
-------------------------
123ABC  456DEF
456DEF  789GHI   123ABC
349UYH  286IWD
q)update SourceId:FirstID^dictMap FirstID from input
FirstID SecondID SourceId
-------------------------
123ABC  456DEF   123ABC
456DEF  789GHI   123ABC
349UYH  286IWD   349UYH
```

See: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/fill/

Comment: `?` find can also be used `update SourceId:FirstID^FirstID SecondID?FirstID from input`

Comment: Oh yes good one that is an easier method! See https://code.kx.com/q/ref/find/#find for more details.

Comment: On a side note, you can use below to create the dictionary mapping
q)exec SecondID by FirstID from input
-->
123ABC| 456DEF
349UYH| 286IWD
456DEF| 789GHI
note: only works if the IDs are distinct